# If-statement doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem where my `if` statement doesn't work. I want the PHP variables to match fields in the database before inserting it to the database. Somehow, when there is written bullsh*t in the HTML input and crosschecked with the database and it doesn't match, it still saves the variable in the database.

How do I solve this?

The following code is used:

```
if(isset($_POST ["SettInnM"])) {
    $ManuellTagnavn = $_POST["TagnavnM"];
    //$ManuellTagnavn = strtoupper($ManuellTagnavn);
    $annexaM = substr($ManuellTagnavn,0,2);
    $annexb1M = substr($ManuellTagnavn,2,-4);
    $sequenceNrM = substr($ManuellTagnavn,4,-1);
    $paralellItem = substr($ManuellTagnavn,7);
    $dato = date("d/m/Y");
    $prosjektID = $_SESSION["prosjekt_id"];

    $sql = "Select plass from annexa where plass = '$annexaM'";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    $query = "Select format from annexb1 where format = '$annexb1M'";
    $res2 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    echo "$annexaM"; 
    echo "$annexb1M"; 

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0 AND mysqli_num_rows($res2) > 0 ) {
        //Check if there are any match with one of the fielde in the database? If it matches, save in database
        $sql = "Select prosjekttag, prosjekt_id from tagnavn where prosjekttag = '$ManuellTagnavn' AND prosjekt_id = '$prosjektID'";
        $resultat = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultat) == 0) {
            $sql = "Insert into tagnavn(prosjekttag, startdato, prosjekt_id, opprettav)" //ENDRET AV ZLATAN 
                ."values ('$ManuellTagnavn', '$dato', '$prosjektID', '$userRow[username]')"; //ENDRET AV KAMALAN
            $resultat = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        } else {
            $resultat = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $query = "Select format from annexb1 where format = '".$annexb1M."'"; write your query like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0 AND mysqli_num_rows($res2) > 0 ) //Cehck if there are any match with one of the fielde in the database? If it matches, save in database
```

this part of you code won't "check for any match with one of the fields in the database", rather since you are using the AND operator it will require both conditions to be true.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultat) == 0)
```

Returns the number of rows in the result set http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_num_rows.asp

***addition on your quest***

> if you want to check both $res AND $res2 it is better for you to echo both of them and see if they return anything mysqli_result object. If you are getting false then you better consider checking the error on the query. 
>   Otherwise you can proceed and check both of the conditions as you did. i.e.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($res2) > 0 )
```

> Note: this will require both conditions to be true. So if you want **at least one condition** to be true use the **|| (OR) operator**.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to how I can crosscheck with values in database and if it matches proceed in IF-statement?

Comment: Please, see the edited response and let me know if i have got the heart your question?